# YAML parse return object not Array using PHP

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I want to use a YAML configuration file, for that, I download `symfony/yaml` package using composer.

I create my test YAML file content:

```
testing:
  test: 2
```

and to parse it I use this code :

```
$yaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('test.yml'));
var_dump($yaml->testng);
```

But, I get this error 'Trying to get property 'testng' of non-object' because the parse return array and I want to get an object.

I tried to add `(object)` but it works just for the first attribute.

Is there any solution?

Comment: This may help, but it looks like the yaml needs to be in Yaml::DUMP_OBJECT format https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#advanced-usage-flags

Comment: There seems to be something very wrong if your error message indicates **testng** causes an error when that string is not even in your input YAML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#parsing-and-dumping-objects-as-maps) you should just pass `Yaml::PARSE_OBJECT_FOR_MAP` as a second parameter of `Yaml::parse()`:

```php
$yaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('test.yml'), Yaml::PARSE_OBJECT_FOR_MAP);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
  public function toObject($array) {
        $obj = new stdClass();
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            $obj->$key = is_array($val) ? $this->toObject($val) : $val;
        }
        return $obj;
    }
```